# Overriding subinterface methods

Tags: java, interface, overriding, extends

Is there any representable example where it is useful to override subinterface methods? Look at the following example:

```
public class TestOverridingSubinterfaceMethods {

    @Test
    public void testOverrideSubinterfaceMethod() throws Exception {
        assertThat(new I2Impl().foo(), is(2));

    }

    private class I2Impl implements I2 {
        @Override
        public Integer foo() {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    private interface I1 {
        Integer foo();
    }

    private interface I2 extends I1 {
        Integer foo();
    }

}
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking.

Comment: @bradimus What is overriding subinterface methods good for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both `I1` and `I2` don't implement `foo()` (and we know they don't in pre-Java 8 versions), it doesn't make sense for `I2` to declare `foo()` again. It's equivalent to `I2` being simply an empty interface that extends `I1`.

In Java 8, however, there are default methods, which allow you to supply default implementation to interface methods. You could have one default implementation of `foo()` in `I1` and a different default implementation of `foo()` in `I2`. In that scenario it could make sense for `I2`'s `foo()` to override `I1`'s `foo()`.

Comment: What if the contracts of `I1#foo()` is completely different from that of `I2#foo()`? In standard library, e.g. see `Map.entrySet()` and `SortedMap.entrySet()`. Both of them eloquently describe the behavior expected from the implementations.